# Adding Multiple UItextfield with same Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a query regarding multiple UItextField added on UIView. I have a subclass of UItextField and in a UIViewController, I am running a for loop as below

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  PinField *pinfiledObject =[PinField all]initWithFrame : myFrame];
   [self.view addSubView: pinfiledObject ];
}
```

After adding fields I have registered with [BehavioSec](http://www.behaviosec.com/) as below

```
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      PinField *pinfiledObject =;[PinField all]initWithFrame : myFrame];
       [self.view addSubView: pinfiledObject ];
       [BehavioSec shared]registerField:pinfiledObject  withTarget:@"pinfield"]];
    }
```

Now problem is that Behaviosec treats each field as different UItextField object. So my question is that, 
Is there any way to create each UItextfield as a unique textfield so that BehavioSec treat each field as the same textfield?

Sorry If my question is wrong or foolish but I am struggling with this issue.

Comment: ohhh no negative mark please..as I want your advice here..May be I am not aware any property of UItextField.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a tag for each view. The preferred way is to create an enum for easier readability or you can just set them to your variable in your loop. Then each view has a unique identifier to use.

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   PinField *pinfiledObject =[PinField all]initWithFrame : myFrame];
   pinfiledObject.tag = i;
   [self.view addSubView: pinfiledObject ];
}
```